# Javascript to display multiple records from a struct

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development

I am trying to build some Javascript using Web3js to list out nested structs.  Specifically, I have designed a customer struct through a mapping.  I have nested in the customer struct two additional mappings - billto and shipto information.  I want to build a UI in Javascript using Web3js to list out all the customer's bill to and ship to information.  I am struggling to figure out how to get it to display through Javascript.  Here is the code to the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Customer {

function Customer() public{}

struct CustomerData {
    address custAddress;
    bytes32 customerName;
    bytes32 physicalAddr1;
    bytes32 physicalAddr2;
    bytes16 physicalCity;
    bytes8 physicalState;
    bytes8 physicalZipCode;
    bytes8 physicalCountry;
    int CreditLimit;  //Customer credit limit
    int CreditBalance;  //running balance the customer has

    //address[] billtoIndex; //billto index
    //uint256 custIndex;
    mapping(address=>Billto) billto;
    mapping(address=>Shipto) shipto;
    bool isEntity; //flag to show if entity already in blockchain
}

struct Billto {
    address BilltoAddr;
    bytes32 BilltoName;
    bytes32 physicalAddr1;
    bytes32 physicalAddr2;
    bytes16 physicalCity;
    bytes8 physicalState;
    bytes8 physicalZipCode;
    bytes8 physicalCountry;
    bool isEntity;


}

struct Shipto {
    address ShiptoAddr;
    bytes32 ShiptoName;
    bytes32 physicalAddr1;
    bytes32 physicalAddr2;
    bytes16 physicalCity;
    bytes8 physicalState;
    bytes8 physicalZipCode;
    bytes8 physicalCountry;
    bool isEntity;
}

    mapping(address => CustomerData) public customers;
    event addNewCustomer (address indexed CustAddr, bytes32 indexed CustName) ;  //add customer info to blockchain log
    event addBillto(address indexed CustAddr, address indexed BillAddr, bytes32 Name, bytes32 Addr1, bytes32 Addr2, bytes16 City, bytes8 State, bytes8 Zip, bytes8 Country) ; 
    event addShipto(address indexed CustAddr, address indexed ShipAddress, bytes32 Name, bytes32 Addr1, bytes32 Addr2, bytes16 City, bytes8 State, bytes8 Zip, bytes8 Country) ; 

// Add a new customer w/ relevant information
function newCustomer(address CustAddr, bytes32 Name, bytes32 Addr1, bytes32 Addr2, bytes16 City, bytes8 State, bytes8 Zip, bytes8 Country) public {

    customers[CustAddr].custAddress = CustAddr;
    customers[CustAddr].customerName = Name;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalAddr1 = Addr1;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalAddr2 = Addr2;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalCity = City;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalState = State;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalZipCode = Zip;
    customers[CustAddr].physicalCountry = Country;
    customers[CustAddr].CreditLimit = 0;
    customers[CustAddr].CreditBalance = 0;
    customers[CustAddr].isEntity = true;
    addNewCustomer(CustAddr, Name);

}
//add Bill to address
function newBillto(address CustAddr, address BillAddr, bytes32 Name, bytes32 Addr1, bytes32 Addr2, bytes16 City, bytes8 State, bytes8 Zip, bytes8 Country) public returns (string confirmed) {

        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].BilltoAddr = BillAddr;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].BilltoName = Name;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalAddr1 = Addr1;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalAddr2 = Addr2;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalCity = City;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalState = State;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalZipCode = Zip;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].physicalCountry = Country;
        customers[CustAddr].billto[BillAddr].isEntity = true;
        confirmed = "Bill to address added";
        addBillto(CustAddr, BillAddr, Name, Addr1, Addr2, City, State, Zip, Country);
//    }



}
  //add Ship to address
function newShipto(address CustAddr, address ShipAddr, bytes32 Name, bytes32 Addr1, bytes32 Addr2, bytes16 City, bytes8 State, bytes8 Zip, bytes8 Country) 
public returns (string confirmed) {

        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].ShiptoName = Name;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalAddr1 = Addr1;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalAddr2 = Addr2;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalCity = City;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalState = State;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalZipCode = Zip;
        customers[CustAddr].shipto[ShipAddr].physicalCountry = Country;
        addShipto(CustAddr, ShipAddr, Name, Addr1, Addr2, City, State, Zip, Country);
        return "Shipto added.";

}    


function adjustCreditLimit(address CustAddr, int newLimit)public returns (string confirmed){
    customers[CustAddr].CreditLimit = newLimit;    
    confirmed = "Customer credit limit changed";
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an array of structs in Solidity yet, so you have at least two options:

1- Have your function return multiple arrays like so:

```
function getMultipleRecords() returns (uint[], uint[], address[]){
  //pseudocode
  uint[] integerData = [];
  uint[] someOtherData = [];
  address[] addressData = [];
  for each struct in your struct array {
    integerData.push(struct.intData);
    someOtherData.push(struct.someOtherData);
    addressData.push(struct.addressData);
  }  

  return (integerData,someOtherData,addressData);

}
```

Then in JS you could piece back the struct together.

2- You could have a function that returns the array length and then in JS for each element call a function that returns that given element.

```
function getOneRecord(uint index) returns (uint, uint, address){
  return (array[index].integerData, array[index].someOtherData, array[index].addressData);
}
```

Then you just piece the struct back together.

Method 1 requires more gas to execute and looks messy, but will retrieve the data in just one call. Method 2 will execute multiple calls (1 call per record) to the contract, but its simpler to code and will consume little gas per call , compared to Method 1, no matter the amount of records.